# May I save a tex file as a picture file?

Tags: graphics, standalone, jpeg

Is there a way to save or export a `tex` file so as to produce a jpg/jpeg/png file?

Comment: Probably related? [Exporting .png or .jpg files directly from LaTeX code. Possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222870/134144)

Comment: The `standalone` class has a `convert` option that is precisely made for that. There are several examples on this site, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301505) is a post by the package author. In addition, if you produce the pictures with `asymptote`, there is the `settings.outformat` directive, e.g. `settings.outformat = "png";`.

Comment: Is it a one-time job or do you want to do many pictures? If it's a one-time job, than I would use an online PDF-to-x converter.

Comment: @leandris, @ Schrödinger's cat I am just trying to save a plain text file in tex in the jpg-format. Perhaps there is a straightforward solution in what you link to, but I do not see it yet.

Comment: Maybe provide a little example. Does the related link help?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I was hoping for a permanent solution, for the online conversion sites are rather proprietary.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner An example could be a small poem in ascii.

Comment: Then install the software **ImageMagick**, is provides the command line `convert` which can be used for conversion. Or use **GhostScript**.

Comment: So you just want to export the PDF that is produced by LaTeX (a single page) in a pixel-based file format like jpg or png, correct?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I will look into that.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php and download the appropriate version. In my case (Windows) it is `ImageMagick-7.0.9-12-Q16-x64-dll.exe` (as of 2019-12-29).
2. Go to https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html and download the appropriate version. In my case (Windows) it is `Ghostscript 9.50 for Windows (32 bit)` (GNU Affero General Public License). **ImageMagick** calls **ghostscript** for converting PDF as far as I understand.
3. Generate a LaTeX file (`test.tex`) and produce a single PDF page.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

---

4. In the same folder, create a text (`myConvertBatch.txt`) file with the following content (`-density 300` is for better quality/resolution).

---

```
magick -density 300 test.pdf test.png 
pause
```

---

5. Rename the text file to `myConvertBatch.bat`.
6. Double-click on `myConvertBatch.bat` -- this should generate `test.png`.
7. Look into the `standalone` document class (https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone).

For more details about the options of the `magick` command, see https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php.

[image]

[image]

### Related

- https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16045
- http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19367
- [Standalone Package | Convert Option | Issues With Command Option | PNG Export | Remove Alpha | Remove Transparency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301455)
- [Exporting .png or .jpg files directly from LaTeX code. Possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222870)

Comment: Thanks! I do not succeed in installing Homebrew.

Comment: @Sapiens Don't know what `Homebrew` means?! Going to bed now anyway, it's 04:38 o'clock in the morning for me :) (China timezone).

Comment: Imagemagick recommends and use Homebrew commands for installation explanations for Mac-users.

Comment: https://brew.sh/

Comment: Thank you for the ample answer! I hope I will be able to implement it soon by installing the appropriate software.