# create PNG in bulk varying numbers in latex code

Tags: png

The following code creates the graphic below (credit to @Schrödinger's cat):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    numbersrow/.style={
        matrix,
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            minimum size=1.6em,
            anchor=center,
            draw,
            node contents=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[numbersrow](a){&&&&&&&&&\\};
\draw[->, shorten > =5pt, shorten <=5pt] (a-1-3.center)--(a-1-4.center);
\draw[->, shorten > =5pt, shorten <=5pt] (a-1-4.center)--(a-1-5.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I use this code to create and save as PNG this kind of images in bulk, varying the numbers inside the boxes?

Within each image, the numbers inside the boxes varies from X to X+9. And for each image X is a single integer from 1 to 1000. So I would end up with 1000 different images. Thanks

Comment: LaTeX-related programs are not made for PNG output. You could use other conversion tools e.g. `inkscape` to do that

Answer (score 2):

I hope to read your question correctly. When I compile

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm,png, convert={
        true,
        density = 300,
        convertexe = {convert},
        }]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Y in {1,...,100}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path coordinate (aux) foreach \X in {1,...,10}
  {node[anchor=west,minimum size={1.2*width("1000")},draw,
  label={[name=l-\Y-\X,inner sep=0.25pt]center:{$\the\numexpr10*\Y+\X$}}] 
  (aux) at (aux.east){}}
  foreach \X in {3,4}
  {(l-\Y-\X) edge[semithick,-stealth] (l-\Y-\the\numexpr\X+1)};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex -shell-escape` on *my* machine, I get 100 png files. I stress *my* machine because this relies on the `convert` command that I have installed on my machine, i.e. as @BambOo is saying we need to rely on external tools at some level. Unfortunately I am not very well versed with all these external tools, so in case this does not work I would not know how to change the conversion command. [Threads like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301455/194703) may shed more light on this.